# Dictionary-style definition list plugin

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-field, single

I've discovered the [types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/) plugin, and I'm loving how simple it makes it to add custom post types and their associated field sets.  One need that I've come across that it doesn't fill, however, is creating fields that are supposed to contain a list of items, such as the definitions in a dictionary entry.

Is there another plugin that will allow these kinds of fields to be created, or is it better to just use a multi-line text box and then edit the single-type.php file for the corresponding type to parse a delimited list stored in that box?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on that plugin, the capability to create custom fields is included.